# Change multiple select to a single select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm having an issue with a multiple select. The only way that can works what I am trying to make is with a multiple select, but I need to transform it to a single dropdown select because that way is design.

The question is: How can I transform a multiple select in a single select? I add a screenshot:

- I have it like this:

[image]

and the design should be like this:

[image]

Is there anyway for transform it with html or css without remove the `multiple="multiple"` property?

My tag:
`<select multiple="multiple" class="destination_s input input--select"></select>`

Regards

Comment: Do you want to make a selection in one dropdown, and have that filter the options in the 2nd dropdown? Is the data mapping such that each destination has multiple properties?

Comment: So you want it to look like a single select, but behave like a multi-select?

Comment: @Ghostrydr exactly, that way

Comment: You're going need a library/plugin to do that.

Comment: Maybe it can be done with the Select2 plugin.

Comment: could be @Barmar Let me check it..it could works

Comment: I specially need that the property multiple doesn't be removed

Comment: This is just a bad idea. A user would not even expect from clicking a dropdown that they would be able to select multiple, and so they would not even be aware that this functionality is possible in the first place. If anything, you should utilize other components, e.g. buttons to Add/Remove the selected option, and a box to show which options are selected. But a combobox (`<select multiple>`) is probably best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I see is to stylize a div that looks like an HTML select and with JavaScript show and hide the select Multiple. This is a quick example I just made (maybe the code could be better):

```js
function showSelect(classname) {
            document.getElementById('sel').className = classname;
        }
```

```css
.hidden {
            display: none;
        }

        .visible {
            display: block;
        }

        .div {
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100px;
        }

        #sel {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .arrow {
            float: right;
        }
```

```html
<div class="div" onmouseover="showSelect('visible')" onmouseout="showSelect('hidden')">
         Choose... <span class="arrow">&#9660;</span>

        <select multiple="multiple" class="hidden" id="sel">
            <option value="">1</option>
            <option value="">2</option>
            <option value="">3</option>
            <option value="">4</option>
            <option value="">5</option>
            <option value="">6</option>
            <option value="">7</option>
            <option value="">8</option>
            <option value="">9</option>
            <option value="">10</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Also consider use a framework like Chosen to make it more easily.

Comment: @JeanManzo If my answer was helpful for you, I would appreciate that you mark it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

i got your point but it cant be possible with the help of HTML/CSS only.
You need have JS or jQuery at some point.

Please refer below plugins which might help you to sort it out.
http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/
https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Multiple-Select-With-Checkboxes-multi-select-js.html

you can also use Chosen, Select2 Plugins too.